# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I have written:

```
create table employee (
emp_id int, 
emp_first_name varchar(20), 
emp_last_name varchar(20), 
dept_id int,
email varchar(255),
primary key(emp_id, dept_id)
);

create table department(
    dept_id int primary key,
    dept_name varchar(255),
    gm_no int,
    foreign key(dept_id) references employee(dept_id)
);
```

but when I try to create the department table, it gives me the error(ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint)

all help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the logic backwards.  The `dept_id` is defined in the `department` table as the primary key.  The `foreign key` constraint belongs in the tables that *reference* the department:

```
create table department(
    dept_id int primary key,
    dept_name varchar(255),
    gm_no int
);

create table employee (
    emp_id int, 
    emp_first_name varchar(20), 
    emp_last_name varchar(20), 
    dept_id int,
    email varchar(255),
    primary key(emp_id, dept_id)
    foreign key (dept_id) references department (dept_id)
);
```

Note that this data structure seems suspicious.  I would expect a company called `employee` to have a unique id for `empid`.  Period.

Employees are obvious in departments, but that could change over time.  You would then want *another* table, say `employeeDepartment` that captured the changing relationship over time.

Your data model, for instance, would get confusing if an employee starts in department A, switches to B, and then returns to A.

Answer (score 1):

The dept_id in the employee table is not key of any type. Make the dept_in column a KEY, UNIQUE KEY, or PRIMARY KEY on the employee. In your situation, just making it UNIQUE KEY is enough.

Answer (score 1):

**As @Sharofiddin said:**

```
create table employee (
emp_id int, 
emp_first_name varchar(20), 
emp_last_name varchar(20), 
dept_id int,
email varchar(255),
primary key(emp_id),
UNIQUE KEY (dept_id) /* add this line and run the query again */
);

create table department(
    dept_id int primary key,
    dept_name varchar(255),
    gm_no int,
    foreign key(dept_id) references employee(dept_id)
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: It seems highly, highly unlikely that the OP wants a data model where a department has at most one employee.  I can understand how you would provide this answer, but not how it gets upvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry sir but I am sorry, I can;t understand what you're saying. Please explain me. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I get it now from your answer. Don't mind please.